# MVC - Ajax.BeginForm - Posting multiple times

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a contact form, the model consists of simply.. Name, email, phone number etc.

On the model I have some simple required attributes on some of the properties.

This is all working great, when no validation errors occurred I get an email saying the form has been submitted, and a nice little "thank you" message is displayed to the user.

My issue is when the validation fails. I get the usual red border on the textboxes etc. Now if the user updates the textboxes to match the validation requirements and submits again, I am getting two emails.  Both the exact same details in them.  It seems however many times you fail the validation that is how many calls (emails) I receive.

I am pretty new to MVC so if you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Cheers,

J

Form:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessContact", "Contact", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "subContentWrapper", }))
            {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()

            <p>
                <strong>Please tell us a little about you and the nature of your enquiry </strong>
            </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "textBox" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Company Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyName, new { @class = "textBox" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        E-mail:
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "textBox" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Phone:
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, new { @class = "textBox" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br />
            <br />
            <p style="text-align: center">
                <input type="submit" value="Contact Us" /></p>
            }
        }
```

Code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ContactService.ProcessContactSubmission(model))
            {
                ViewBag.Sent = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Sent = false;
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry an error has occured, please try again later.");
            }
            return PartialView("~/Views/Modules/Contact Us/Main.cshtml", model);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Sent = false;
            return PartialView("~/Views/Modules/Contact Us/Main.cshtml", model);
        }
```

ContactService.ProcessContactSubmission(model) - This just sends the email and returns true/false

Comment: I've updated the post to include a code snipplet. Thanks

Comment: what is "subContentWrapper"? is it a DIV surrounding the AJAX form?

Comment: that is the div I am updating the content of - that all works fine and as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@jamie, Can you check in firebug if the form is submitted multiple times or not? If possible please post the ProcessContactSubmission code as well. also I hope that 
if (ModelState.IsValid) is not in a loop or something, if it is then please let us know what

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but thought I'd throw my findings into the hat.

I had the same thing today where I had a form being submitted using a submit button within the ajax form and every time I submitted it the number of posts was multiplying!

Having checked everything, no duplicate unobtrusive js files etc, I simply changed the submit button to a standard input tag which manually submits the form and hey presto, single post only!

```
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="$('#formtosubmit').submit();" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" />
```

Hope it helps others